# How to send error before an Observable has been created

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been trying figure out how to handle this, but how do you send an error to a subscription in a function when the observable hasn't been created yet?

Take the example below, I create the subject, and test for valid input. If it is invalid how do I create an observer and send it an error? With what I have below error has been sent but the observer hasn't returned yet.

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
  public myFunction(first: string, last: string) {
    let sub = new Subject<boolean>()
    if(first.trim().length === 0 || last.trim().length === 0) {
      sub.error(new Error('Invalid String'))
      return sub.asObservable()
    }

    this.httpClient
        .post('/endpoint', JSON.stringify({first, last}))
        .subscribe(result => sub.next(result))

    return sub.asObservable()
  }
}
```

Comment: I would `throw` on error, then use `try`, `catch` from the calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update/Correction** [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgju8g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You can use subject error method and create error even if you are not subscribe to the subject. and when you subscribe to it. it will get the error notification.

Both error and complete method will send notification to all the old subscriber and even if new subscriber comes into picture. that new will also get that error or complete notification.

your code should work.

```
constructor() {
  this.subjectFunction()
   .subscribe(
     response => console.log(response),
     error => console.log(error), //the control will goes here after error notification
     () => console.log('completed'))
}

subjectFunction() {
    let sub = new Subject<boolean>()
    if(first.trim().length === 0 || last.trim().length === 0) { // if this is true
      sub.error({error: 'Invalid String'})
      return sub.asObservable()
    }
    return sub;
}
// Console Output: {error: 'Invalid String'}
```

**You can also use throwError in rxjs**
Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits an error notification.

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
//.....
return throwError({error: 'Invalid Data'});
//......
```

**OLD**

`The below solution is for handling new emits before returning observables/subject. not for error`

There are different ways to handle this.
Mentioning only few of them. It depends on business need.

**1. Using SetTimeout function**

```
    if(first.trim().length === 0 || last.trim().length === 0) {
      setTimeout(() = {
        sub.next({data: 'String'})
      }, 0)
      return sub.asObservable()
    }
```

**2. Using Replay Subject**

```
    let sub = new ReplaySubject(1)
    if(first.trim().length === 0 || last.trim().length === 0) {
      sub.next({data: 'String'})
      return sub.asObservable()
    }
```

**3. Behavior Subject and AsyncSubject can also be used

Comment: If I return two different observables the subscription is still run right? A subscription isn't bound to a particular observable right?

Comment: yes!. you can subscribe to any observable. The only condition is it should be active at the time of subscribing. Also you can use AsyncSubject for the above thing, like i said there are different ways to handle this.